# Play Framework 2 two-factor authentication?

Tags: playframework-2.0, two-factor-authentication

I'm wondering if there are any good libraries out there for implementing two-factor auth with a Play Framework 2 app using [SecureSocial](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial)? I've done a good amount of Googling, and have turned up nothing.

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: nope, still nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

[Silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette) is a Play module that supports Two Factor Authentication. Silhouette was originally a fork of SecureSocial so perhaps you can reasonably easily switch to Silhouette. However, I think it's been fairly heavily rewritten so perhaps won't be so easy after all.

I use Silhouette myself and it works fine, but I haven't tested two factor authentication yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I use:
https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate.

The library uses aswel deadbolt2 (https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2) for authorization.